# Остановка setInterval при определенном ответе

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Имеется следующий JQuery код. Как мне остановить setInterval (прекратить отправку AJAX'a) если в success придёт ответ **1**, допустим.

```
function poll() {

            $.ajax({
                url: "/checkqiwipayment",
                type: "POST",
               data: {
                 qiwi: $("#qiwi").val() , 
                 currency:$("#currency").val() , 
                 wallet:$("#wallet").val() ,
                _csrf:$("#_csrf").val(),
             },
                success: function(data) {

                },
        });
    }

setInterval(poll, 3500);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Присваиваете свой интервал какой нибудь переменной

```
var interval = setInterval(poll, 3500)
```

Внутри success:

```
success: function(data) {
    if (data === 1) {
         clearInterval(interval)
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6):

Ответ по сути вашего вопроса, в общих чертах дал уже Илья Паймушкин, но я бы хотел отметить, что `setInterval` - это не самый удачный метод для вызова Ajax-запроса в цикле. Чтобы это понять, можно представить такую ситуацию, что на предыдущий запрос уйдёт столько же времени, сколько и выставленная задержка в `setInterval`. В этом случае, интервал между запросами уменьшится до нуля. Думаю, вы понимаете, что будет, если время запроса превысит время задержки.
Поэтому, если конечно нет веских причин, я бы рекомендовал вам переходить к следующему запросу, только после завершения предыдущего:

```
(function poll() {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/checkqiwipayment',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            /* */
        },
        success: function(data) {
            if (data !== 1) {
                setTimeout(poll, 1000);
            }

        },
    });
}());
```

Comment: Только не success, а complete/always.

Comment: Кстати да, хорошее замечание, спасибо.